# Variable is not changing. Where is the mistake?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do a simple slider using a flag, but i believe its value isn't changing when I say so. I'm a beginner so it's probably a stupid mistake, any help? By the way, it could also be a mistake in the classes that i'm adding but i'm not sure.

Here is my code, just pay attention to the js or the last three classes in css. I know the error is there but can't find it.

```js
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev'),
  next = document.querySelector('#next'),
  one = document.querySelector('.slide1'),
  two = document.querySelector('.slide2'),
  three = document.querySelector('.slide3');

var flag = 1;

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == 0) {
    one.classList.add('middle');
    two.classList.add('right');
    three.classList.add('left');
    flag = 1;
  } else if (flag == 1) {
    one.classList.add('left');
    two.classList.add('middle');
    three.classList.add('right');
    flag = 2;
  } else if (flag == 2) {
    one.classList.add('right');
    two.classList.add('left');
    three.classList.add('middle');
    flag = 0;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide1 {
  background: pink;
}

.slide2 {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background: teal;
}

.slide3 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: yellow;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 40;
  top: 135px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev {
  left: 10px;
}

#next {
  right: 10px;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.middle {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="prev" class="btn"></button>
  <div class="slide1 slide">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide2 slide">
    <h1>Two</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="slide3 slide">
    <h1>Three</h1>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="next" class="btn"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you believe is wrong here and what your desired results are.

Comment: You're only adding classes, don't you want to remove them as well when sliding through?

Comment: Maybe you need to remove old classes before adding the new ones, your code adds a class to every slide on each click.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you are only adding the classes.

I think you were intending to also use `classList.remove()` to remove classes that shouldn't be applied anymore.

```js
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev'),
      next = document.querySelector('#next'),
      one = document.querySelector('.slide1'),
      two = document.querySelector('.slide2'),
      three = document.querySelector('.slide3');

var flag = 1;

next.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (flag == 0) {
    one.classList.add('middle');
    one.classList.remove('left', 'right');
    two.classList.add('right');
    two.classList.remove('left', 'middle');
    three.classList.add('left');
    three.classList.remove('middle', 'right');
    flag = 1;
  }
  else if (flag == 1) {
    one.classList.add('left');
    one.classList.remove('middle', 'right');
    two.classList.add('middle');
    two.classList.remove('left', 'right');
    three.classList.add('right');
    three.classList.remove('left', 'middle');
    flag = 2;
  }
  else if (flag == 2) {
    one.classList.add('right');
    one.classList.remove('left', 'middle');
    two.classList.add('left');
    two.classList.remove('middle', 'right');
    three.classList.add('middle');
    three.classList.remove('left', 'right');
    flag = 0;
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

.slide1 {
  background: pink;
}

.slide2 {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  background: teal;
}

.slide3 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: yellow;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 40;
  top: 135px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#prev {
  left: 10px;
}

#next {
  right: 10px;
}

.left {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.middle {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.right {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Try</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <button type="button" id="prev" class="btn"></button>

  <div class="slide1 slide"><h1>One</h1></div>
  <div class="slide2 slide"><h1>Two</h1></div>
  <div class="slide3 slide"><h1>Three</h1></div>

  <button type="button" id="next" class="btn"></button>
</div>

<script src="./js.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it shows the correct "panel" in your slideshow each time, but I am not certain if the animation is exactly as you intended.

It looks like when scrolling rightwards, the leftmost element "leaps" over the tops of the other two to go to the right.

You can experiment with the elements' [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to put the leftmost or rightmost (depending on direction of scroll) behind the other two elements.

JavaScript can set the z-index using `.style.zIndex`.

Comment: Note that you can add/remove several classes at the same time. Just pass multiple classes as arguments.